# импорт material модуля в kotlin JS приложение

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, material-design

Пытаюсь добавить кнопки из material модуля от Гугл.

https://material.io/develop/web/components/buttons/

Пишу react приложение на Kotlin, хочу потом использовать классы css для кнопок

```
button(classes = "mdc-button") {
            +"Click me"
        }
```

но постоянно ловлю ошибку

```
 Can't resolve '@material/button/mdc-button'
```

Comment: а можете, пожалуйста, показать собственно что подразумевается, что экспортируется?

Comment: ну, я пытаюсь сделать импорт в css файл
@import "@material/button/mdc-button";
как написано в Гайдах, но сам модуль лежит в node_modules проекта.
я нашел способ как это сделать - нужно просто перенести css файлы в нужную директорию из модуля, но такой вариант очень костыльный